# Update Array to reduce Variance

Tags: math, optimization, statistics, standard-deviation, variance

I have an array `X` with float values and a fixed size. I need to add `p` (a float value) to any element of `X` such that the variance of `X` reduces.

How do I select the proper element?

Eg:

```
X = [0,1.2,1.7,2.1,1.7,0,1.3]
```

and

```
p = 0.5
```

What is the new `X`?

Comment: This is a statistics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variance is a meassure of how far values are from the mean.

Therefore, you can evaluate which changed value produces the greater reduction of that meassure.

```
import numpy as np
def Reduce_variance(X, p):
    #Calculate mean
    mean = np.mean(X)
    #Calculate the variance terms
    x=(np.array(X)-mean)**2
    #Calculate the variance terms added p
    y=(np.array(X)+p-mean)**2
    #Calculate the difference
    z=x-y
    #Check the index of the best improvement
    index=np.where(z==max(z))[0][0]
    #Replace
    X[index]=X[index]+p
    return X
```

Answer (score 0):

The variance is determined by how far elements are from the mean. If adding `p` to an element brings that element closer to the the mean then you will lower the variance. For example:

```
from statistics import variance, mean

X = [0,1.2,1.7,2.1,1.7,0,1.3] 
p = .5

def change(X, p):
    mu = mean(X)
    for n in X:
        if abs(mu - n) > abs(mu - (n + p)):
            yield n + p
        else:
            yield n


variance(X), variance(change(X, p))
# (0.6961904761904762, 0.3747619047619048)
```